# Script to copy text including today's date into clipboard

Tags: windows, script, boot, clipboard, date

I'd like to know if its possible in Windows for a script (or similar) to be written that will copy today's date and specific text into the clipboad, in the following format:

dd/mm/yy - xx - xxx

example

22/12/13 - JS - test note

Also, would like to then know how this script can be:
a) set to run on startup
b) assigned to a specific keyboard shortcut

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure its possible, an easy especially with say PowerShell, or even C# or VB.Net.

A simple PowerShell Script to do as you ask:

```
$curDate = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yy"
$curDate + "JS - Test Note" | clip
```

If I paste out my results:

`21/12/13JS - Test Note`

Now you just need to figure out how you actually want to use it. If on Startup, just add a startup item that calls PowerShell and pipes in the correct .ps1 script.

If you want a hotkey, best bet is to look at something like AutoHot keys. Writing this your self can be a challenge, or caught by Windows as Malware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for introducing me to AutoHotKeys.  It was perfect for what I needed (automating scripts and hotkeys for the team at work) and allows compiling into exe's so the team don't need anything fancy installed. I have now written my first script! No issues with malware :) thanks again

Comment: In a PowerShell script it would be better to use `Set-Clipboard ($curDate + "JS - Test Note")` instead of piping the string to `clip` since the latter would lead to false results if the string contains special characters like `Ä`.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser "False results"? Additionally before PS ~5 I believe clip.exe was *the* way to get this done. (7 year old answer)

Comment: I'm aware the answer is 7 years old, and IMO still a good one. That said, "false results" was probably poorly worded. What I mean is that if i run `"Täst" | clip` on my system the clipboard then contains `Tõst`. I couldn't find out quickly when `Set-Clipboard` was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, for example in C#.

- for the keyboard hook, see [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)
- for clipboard, use [Clipboard.SetText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ydby206k(v=vs.85).aspx)
- for the date, use [DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yy")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)
- for the startup, use the Autostart folder of Windows

It might even be easier using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Because you and the previous answer mentioned autohotkeys, i checked it out and turned out to be perfect for what i needed.  Have now written my first script, thanks :)